# Packages are not installling on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, apt, nginx

I tried to install imagemagick using following command

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing
```

But while installing I get following error

```
nginx-full : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.4.7-1+precise0) but 1.6.0-1+precise0 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to remove the nginx using `sudo apt-get remove nginx` command but getting same error how can I resolve this issue.

**Edit**
By referring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071453/how-to-completely-remove-nginx-from-ubuntu-13-04) 
output of`dpkg -l | grep nginx`

```
iU  nginx                                  1.4.7-1+precise0                                    small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                           1.6.0-1+precise0                                    small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
iF  nginx-full                             1.4.7-1+precise0                                    nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

output of `dpkg -S $(which nginx)`

```
dpkg-query: error: --search needs at least one file name pattern argument
Use --help for help about querying packages.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try **sudo apt-get -f install**?

Comment: yes I tired but getting same error.

Comment: Try to install it from this link [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick#Installation). It will ask you to open the software center. If the software center prompt an error write it back please.

Comment: I am referring same link for installation

Comment: Try to completely remove and reinstall nginx-full. Apparently this is a common dependency problem. Then try to install imagemagick.

Comment: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove nginx* && sudo apt-get install nginx-full**

Comment: Here is a complete [description](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies) of the problem but the solution is long. Reinstalling all the packages will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run :

```
sudo dpkg -r nginx-common
```

If it is successful or not run:

```
gksudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the resulting gedit remove the whole section starts with:

`Package : nginx-common`

then run the installation